# fields_for fails to create object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for, nested-form-for

I'm using form_for and fields_for to create a company, an address, and a company_person.

Here's the relevant part of the Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :company_people
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_people
has_many :addresses, as: :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

I've added the relevant parameters to the Companies controller:

```
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :email, :phone,
  :website, :ein, :description,
  {company_person_params: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email]},
  addresses_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :zipcode])
end
```

And here's the part of the Companies controller that does the work:

```
@company = Company.new
@company.assign_attributes(company_params)
@company.agencies << Agency.first
@company.company_people.build
@company.company_people << @company_person
if @company.save
  flash.notice = "Success!"
```

This is working fine for the address - it's handled by "@company.assign_attributes(company_params)". 
It's saved and I can print it on the confirmation page no problem. But the company_person is not happening. I get a nil exception for everything. I was following this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms but I'm still stuck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `company` object doesn't have a value for `company_person` attribute.  Likely, this is because of the way your models are set up.  your `Company` and `CompanyPerson` model need to have a one-to-many relationship defined:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_people
  #whatever else
end

class CompanyPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  #whatever else
end
```

This is assuming that your primary key is the default `id`.  If not, you need to tell Rails what they are.

You can find more information about ActiveRecord associations here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks. I've solved the associations problem and confirmed that it's not the form that's at fault. I'm going to rewrite my question to match the new information